# How to send NFT from contract to other account

Tags: anchor, nft

In order to send nft to my contract then it can transfer to other accounts, I create an associated account from programId and transfer to that ata. Then how can I transfer NFT from my contract to other accounts?

```
        let tokenAccountOfProgram = await createAssociatedTokenAccount(
            provider.connection,
            owner,
            minter,
            program.programId
        )

        await program.methods
            .createMarketItem(...)
            .accounts({
                // systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
                stateAccount: state_pda.publicKey,
                to: tokenAccountOfProgram,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                user: owner,
                from: tokenAccount,
                authProgram: program.programId
            }).signers([owner]).rpc();
```

This is the code for transfering and its context:

```
        let transfer_instruction = Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, transfer_instruction);
        anchor_spl::token::transfer(cpi_ctx, 1)?;

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateMarketItem<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>, // seller
    #[account(mut)]
    pub state_account: Account<'info, State>,
    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub to: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub auth_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

And this is the code I use for transferring back:

```
    pub fn transfer_back(
        ctx: Context<CreateMarketItem>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let transfer_instruction = Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.auth_program.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, transfer_instruction);
        anchor_spl::token::transfer(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
        Ok(())
    }

// code on client
await program.methods
            .transferBack()
            .accounts({
                // systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
                stateAccount: state_pda.publicKey,
                to: tokenAccountOfProgram,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                user: owner,
                from: tokenAccount,
                authProgram: program.programId
            }).signers([owner]).rpc();
```

It return "Error: AnchorError caused by account: auth_program. Error Code: ConstraintMut. Error Number: 2000. Error Message: A mut constraint was violated.". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transfer an SPL token from a Token account controlled by a PDA of your program, the PDA will need to sign the transfer instruction.

In the example below, `auth` represents the PDA with authority over the token account.

```
    #[account(
        seeds = ["auth".as_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub auth: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
```

And is used to sign the transfer instruction, note to use `CpiContext::new_with_signer`

```
pub fn transfer_handler(ctx: Context<TokenTransfer>) -> Result<()> {
    let seeds = &["auth".as_bytes(), &[*ctx.bumps.get("auth").unwrap()]];
    let signer = [&seeds[..]];

    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        token::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.from_token_account.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.to_token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.auth.to_account_info(),
        },
        &signer,
    );

    token::transfer(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Here is reference:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    token::{self, Mint, Token, TokenAccount},
};

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TokenTransfer<'info> {
    /// CHECK: token account authority PDA
    #[account(
        seeds = ["auth".as_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub auth: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = auth
    )]
    pub from_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = payer
    )]
    pub to_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

// transfer SPL token from PDA token account to user token account
pub fn transfer_handler(ctx: Context<TokenTransfer>) -> Result<()> {
    let seeds = &["auth".as_bytes(), &[*ctx.bumps.get("auth").unwrap()]];
    let signer = [&seeds[..]];

    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        token::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.from_token_account.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.to_token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.auth.to_account_info(),
        },
        &signer,
    );

    token::transfer(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Additionally, you'll also need an instruction in your program to create a Token Account. In the reference below, the PDA is both the address of the Token Account and the authority of the token account.

```
// create PDA token account
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{Mint, Token, TokenAccount};
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Init<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = auth,
        seeds = ["auth".as_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    /// CHECK: PDA
    #[account(
        seeds = ["auth".as_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub auth: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
}

pub fn init_handler(_ctx: Context<Init>) -> Result<()> {
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Hi @john, tks for your answer but when change the code called from client: const [pda, bump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
   [Buffer.from('auth')],
   program.programId
  )

  await program.methods
   .transferBack()
   .accounts({
    toTokenAccount: tokenAccountOfProgram,
    auth: pda,
    fromTokenAccount: tokenAccount,
    mint: minter,
   }).signers([owner]).rpc();
It return "A token owner constraint was violated." error

Comment: You have to use the seeds of the PDA you used as the authority of the program's Token Account when you created the token account

Comment: I created the ata but it return "Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account". Here is the code: await program.methods
   .transferBack()
   .accounts({
    toTokenAccount: tokenAccount,
    auth: pda,
    fromTokenAccount: tokenAccountOfProgram.address,
    mint: minter,
   }).signers([owner]).rpc(); Is it because the signers is wrong?

Comment: If you're trying to transfer a token from the PDA Token Account (decrease its balance), the PDA has to be included as a signer in the transfer instruction. 

Here's some reference for CPIs in Anchor: https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/cross-program-invocations

Here's some reference for PDAs in Anchor: https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/pdas

Comment: Yeah I included the pda as a signer in transfer ix like your code

Comment: Change to_token_account to mut will solve the problem. Thanks for your answers